# Creating lambda function requiring at least one environment variable

Tags: lambda, terraform

I'm having an issue creating two lambda functions. My "controller" function deploys with no issue but my "chunker" function throws an error "Error: At least one field is expected inside environment"

Both functions are nearly identical, with differing zip files and environment variables.

```
  function_name = format("ancb-chunker-%s",var.env)

  s3_bucket = aws_s3_bucket.ancb["lambda"].id
  s3_key = var.lambda_zip_chunker

  handler = "handler.chunker"
  runtime = "nodejs8.10"

  role = aws_iam_role.lambda_exec.arn

  environment {
      variables = {
          TEST = "yes"
          ORIGINAL_BUCKET = aws_s3_bucket.ancb["original"].id
          TO_PROCESS_BUCKET = aws_s3_bucket.ancb["to-process-prod"].id
          ENVIRONMENT = var.env
          CHUNK_SIZE = 5000
      }
  }
  tags = {
      Environment = var.env
      Terraform = true
  }
}
resource "aws_lambda_function" "ancb_controller" {

  function_name = format("ancb-controller-%s",var.env)

  s3_bucket = aws_s3_bucket.ancb["lambda"].id
  s3_key = var.lambda_zip_controller

  handler = "handler.controller"
  runtime = "nodejs8.10"

  role = aws_iam_role.lambda_exec.arn

  environment {
      variables = {
          DESTINATION_BUCKET = aws_s3_bucket.ancb["destination"].id
          ENVIRONMENT = var.env
          ERROR_BUCKET = aws_s3_bucket.ancb["error"].id
          GEOCODIO_APIKEY = <removed>
          GEOCODIO_ENDPOINT = <removed>
          GEOCODIO_VERSION = "v1.3"
          ORIGINAL_BUCKET = aws_s3_bucket.ancb["original"].id
          SOURCE_BUCKET = aws_s3_bucket.ancb["source"].id
          TO_PROCESS_BUCKET = aws_s3_bucket.ancb["to-process"].id
          WORKING_BUCKET = aws_s3_bucket.ancb["working"].id
      }
  }
  tags = {
      Environment = var.env
      Terraform = true
  }
}
```

Here is the error received:

```
Error: At least one field is expected inside environment

  on .terraform/modules/ancb/services/ancb/main.tf line 29, in resource "aws_lambda_function" "ancb_chunker":
  29: resource "aws_lambda_function" "ancb_chunker" {
```

I expect the code to work for both but in my testing the environment variables that I set for "chunker" don't work. If I put the environment variables for "controller" in the "chunker" variables, I'm able to create the function with no issue...

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the full error please?

Comment: I just edited to include the full error.

Comment: Does it actually create the controller function properly or is it failing before it gets there?

Comment: It creates the controller function properly but fails to create the chunker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was my mistake.. The to process bucket doesn't exist instead it needs to be ["to-process"]  TO_PROCESS_BUCKET = aws_s3_bucket.ancb["to-process-prod"].id.

Sorry for wasting everyone's time.

Answer (score 1):

Lambdas do not require any environment variables set.

You are however passing in var.env, without knowing more of your issue I would look here.

Comment: But the var.env variable is being passed into the controller function with no problem.